# DataSourceTransactionManager and test for active transaction

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-jdbc

I have a simple app that use `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager` to manage the transactions.
My spring config is as follow:

```
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

I have annotated the method with `@Transactional` and print out the `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()`

But the out put is `false`. What have i done wrong ?

Edit: i forgot to say that i test that with `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class`. I included the `TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class` and this will not work. Now it worked after i extend the class with `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to add the below to your cfg file. this is required when you are using annotations. Have you added this?

```
<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

Here is the namespace

```
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd">
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the required annotations on your test class?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/spring-....xml")
@TestExecutionListeners({TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class, DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class})
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public class MyTest {
 ...
}
```

I'm not sure whether the last two are really necessary, I want my test cases to have an active transaction that's why I need those. The first three should be enough in order to get transactional proxies for your annotated beans.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, you should use this instead:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```